# how to create a string which can be used as an array in python?

Tags: python

i want to create a string S , which can be used as an array , as in each element can be used separately by accesing them as an array.

Comment: You should add more details. Python strings are already working like lists. What *exactly* do you want? Provide an example, a context, a problem, so that one understands what you're after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how Python strings already work:

```
>>> a = "abcd"
>>> a[0]
'a'
>>> a[2]
'c'
```

But keep in mind that this is read only access.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert a string to a list of characters by using `list`, and to go the other way use `join`:

```
>>> s = 'Hello, world!'
>>> l = list(s)
>>> l[7] = 'f'
>>> ''.join(l)
'Hello, forld!'
```

Comment: but then i always get list indexing errors . i would like to define the string as in c++ , where String S , gives me a string S which can be used as an array of characters.

Comment: @mekasperasky: you can't modify the original string, you can only modify the list then convert it back to a string. Strings are immutable in Python. Modifying one character in a string can be an expensive operation as you have to copy the entire string.

Comment: If you are getting index errors then you are probably trying to access characters off the end of the string - you will get the same error whether you are using a string or a list. This is a bug in your code, not a problem with Python's strings or lists.  Show us the code!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ptfQHina

thats the code .. can you try debugging it . its an rc 5 algorithm ..

Comment: @mekasperasky: A lot of that code seems unnecessary. At the start you assign to pt1, and then call append. Then before you've used the resulting value, you assign to it again - destroying the old value. And then on the next line you assign to it a third time. This has to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit surprised that no one seems to have written a popular "MutableString" wrapper class for Python.  I would think that you'd want to have it store the string as a list, returning it via `''.join()` and implement a suite of methods including those for strings (`startswith`, `endswith`, `isalpha` and all its ilk and so one) and those for lists.

For simple operations just operating on the list and using `''.join()` as necessary is fine.  However, for something something like: `'foobar'.replace('oba', 'amca')` when you're working with a list representation gets to be ugly.  (`that=list(''.join(that).replace(something, it))` ... or something like that).  The constant marshaling between list and string representations is visually distracting.

Comment: There is [UserString.MutableString](http://docs.python.org/library/userdict.html#UserString.MutableString) in the standard library, but it's slow and deprecated since 2.6 (removed in 3.0).

Comment: Apparently the bytearray (mutable sequence of bytes) was added back in 2.6: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=bytearray#bytearray